# Xcode 4 Interface Builder: How to set File's Owner

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have myController.h and myController.m defined, and proceeded to create a myController.xib with the Wizard. I can't, however, connect the controls from the xib file to the class interface. Usually when I drop the connection cross hair on the File's Owner icon, it'll show me a list of properties that have been declared as IBOutlet, but this time it's just nothing.

I thought the names of the class files and XIB file (myController) automatically binds File's Owner, but apparently that is not the case.

How can I manually bind the two?

Comment: Not related, but where do I find that Wizard?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Go to the `Identity Inspector` (Cmd+Option+3) and change the class to `myController`.

Comment: I had to select the Files Owner icon first, but it worked now. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Here it is in 5.1:

[image]

I thought I would add this screenshot as it took me some time to find it!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same question... XCode 4.2 enables to create a subclass of UIViewController and there you can optionally check the "with XIB for user interface" option.

*New File... >> UIViewControler subclass >> "with xib..."*

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do it manually... When the world is not using XIB(s) anymore... 
Open the XIB or NIB file in your favourite text editor

you will find this line there...

```
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="MyClassName">
```

Change the `MyClassName` to the class you want to refer it to, save the file and your file's owner will be changed.
Caution: Close Xcode (To auto reload the changes) and also take a backup in case you mess up something.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the same issue while in Xcode 4: while trying to make a connection to file's owner, the icon did not respond while dragging the connection line and hovering over file's owner. Resetting the custom class didn't work. I ended up trying quitting and restarting Xcode and only this did the trick.

Comment: I was having the same problem today.  The File's Owner was correctly set and restarting XCode fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking an answer for the same problema in Xcode 12.1, just set the class for the view, and restart Xcode, it will do the trick.